# Exclude allitems.aspx from search results

Tags: 2013, search, result-source, query-rule

I have a site which contain a few lists. When I search something in my site then it returns following result:

http://server/Lists/Mylist/Allitems.aspx
http://server/Lists/MyList/DispForm.aspx?ID=34
http://server/Lists/Mylist

I only want to display DispForm.aspx in search results and EXCLUDE AllItems.aspx and other views.

I set following crawl rule in CA but it excludes all results and doesn't bring anything when searching something.

> http://*/AllItems.aspx

I searched on this topic and each person is telling a different story. Some say to define query rule some say to define result sources, some say this, some say that etc.

What is sure fire way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had gone through the same exercise and a good post by [Mikael Svenson](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/356/mikael-svenson) on doing just that helped me.

If you append `-contentclass:STS_List_*` to your query template within the query rule or result source, these views will all be excluded. In effect all list landing pages will be removed including:

- AllItems.aspx
- AllPages.aspx
- AllPosts.aspx
- AllCategories.aspx
- Calendar.aspx
- Overview.aspx

His blog post is available [here](http://www.techmikael.com/2014/11/tired-of-getting-allitemsaspx-hits-in.html)

The way to get to the query builder for a Result Source is

Go to **Search Administration** in CA --> Result Sources --> **New Result Source**

[image]

Click **Launch Query Builder**

[image]

Comment: What exactly is this query template?

Comment: The query template would be the query field that is available to you when you create a result source. I have added a screenshot above.