# SharePoint Keyword Query to restrict link to Doc Library, but include content in it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, kql

I'm using a Result Source and successfully pulling back content from a document library.  The issue is the search result include the link to the document library itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is similar to this question, [Exclude allitems.aspx from search results](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/190897/178) so adding -contentclass:STS_List_* should do the trick